# Discord.js v14 DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: discord, discord.js

My discord command does not work due to the error DiscordAPIError[40060]

I've tried seeing what caused it but couldn't heres my code:

`````
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'help') {
    await interaction.deferReply();
    await wait(800);
   await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [helpEmbed] });
    }
});


client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'wombat') {
    await interaction.deferReply();
    await wait(800);
   await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
});````
`````

Comment: Your code looks correct, are you sure you do not have some other code interfering? Your error implies the bot is trying to respond to an interaction multiple times.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another bot running with the same bot-token? If so, stop that bot if you want this instance to reply correctly. They are "stealing" the interactions from each other.